# What is the best way to group objects in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

If I have for example 3 different shapes in SFML, and I want to rotate them all relative to a single center, as if these 3 shapes were inside a square, what would be the best way? 
Would it be leaving them inside a view and rotating the view? 
Or is there some more practical way?

Comment: I am not an SFML expert, but I do believe this is part of what Views are for. You essentially need to map your shapes into the local coordinate system of some entity, then transform that entity.

Comment: This article may be relevant, which mentions creating a hierarchy of objects: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-transform.php

Answer (score 7):

Though approach I am about to propose is not so simple, counter-intuitive in some way, but is much more powerful and every rendering engine uses this in one form or another.
Most rendering and game engines like **Ogre3d** or **Unreal Engine** (actually, its rendering engine) use such things as *Scene Graphs* to group objects and relational coordinate systems to draw them and if you want to dig deep into Computer Graphics, you need to get used to these things.

Let's imagine that you want to write a program that will visualize rotations of  Earth and Moon around Sun.
Suppose, Sun is the center and does not move.
Earth revolves around Sun and this is quite simple to implement.
But there is also Moon which revolves around Earth and its resulting trajectory is quite tricky to calculate and I don't even mention that rotations of the planets are not perfect circles.
And what if we have another pebble that revolves around Moon?
It would be a total mess.

The solution humans came up with is to abstract rotation of Moon from the rotation of Sun.
Moon rotates around Earth, right?
So the trick is to bind rigidly Moon's coordinate system with Earth and implement rotation of Moon just like Sun does not exist.
Another trick is to bind rigidly Earth's coordinate system with Sun and implement rotation of Earth just like Moon and other Universe does not exist.
As you can see, there is clear hierarchy of objects: Sun->Earth->Moon.
In terms of Computer Graphics, Sun is *parent* object for Earth and Earth is *child* object for Sun.
So is with Earth and Moon: Earth is *parent* object for Moon and Moon is *child* object for Earth.
The whole system is called *Scene Graph*.

Unfortunately for us, unlike rendering engines, **SFML** does not provide ready-to-use classes for scene graph, but it provides us tools to implement it.
Here is my implementation:

```
//SceneNode.h
class SceneNode :
    public sf::Transformable,
    public sf::Drawable,
    private sf::NonCopyable {
public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<SceneNode>          Ptr;
    typedef std::pair<SceneNode*, SceneNode*>   Pair;

    explicit                SceneNode();

    void                    AttachChild( Ptr child );
    Ptr                     DetachChild( const SceneNode& node );

private:
    virtual void        draw(
        sf::RenderTarget& target,
        sf::RenderStates states
    ) const;
    virtual void        DrawCurrent(
        sf::RenderTarget& target,
        sf::RenderStates states
    ) const;
    void                DrawChildren(
        sf::RenderTarget& target,
        sf::RenderStates states
    ) const;

    std::vector<Ptr>    mChildren;
    SceneNode*          mParent;
};

//SceneNode.cpp
SceneNode::SceneNode( Category::Type category ) :
mChildren(),
mParent( nullptr ) {}

void
SceneNode::AttachChild( Ptr child ) {
    child->mParent = this;
    mChildren.push_back( std::move( child ) );
}

SceneNode::Ptr
SceneNode::DetachChild( const SceneNode& node ) {
    auto found = std::find_if(
        mChildren.begin(),
        mChildren.end(),
        [&] ( Ptr& p ) { return p.get() == &node; }
    );
    assert( found != mChildren.end() );

    Ptr result      = std::move( *found );
    result->mParent = nullptr;
    mChildren.erase( found );
    return result;
}

void
SceneNode::draw( sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states ) const {
    states.transform *= getTransform();

    DrawCurrent( target, states );
    DrawChildren( target, states );
}

void
SceneNode::DrawCurrent(
    sf::RenderTarget& target,
    sf::RenderStates states
) const {}

void
SceneNode::DrawChildren(
    sf::RenderTarget& target,
    sf::RenderStates states
) const {
    for ( const Ptr& child : mChildren ) {
        child->draw( target, states );
    }
}
```

Any `SceneNode` can be drawn as simple as a rectangle, but after drawing itself, `SceneNode` would draw all its child nodes, if you don't forget to implement `SceneNode::DrawCurrent` method.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, for all I've seen, the simplest and most intuitive way is to put the objects inside the view.

For example:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#define windowWidth  1000
#define windowHeight 600
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), "SFML Views");

    View view(FloatRect(0,0, windowWidth, windowHeight)); // container
    view.zoom(2); // half size to turn transformations visible

    RectangleShape background (Vector2f(windowWidth, windowHeight)); // draw a full rectangle to show the container dimensions
    background.setFillColor(Color::White);

    RectangleShape r1 (Vector2f(100,100)); // 1st object
    r1.setFillColor(Color::Red);
    r1.setPosition(Vector2f(30,10));


    RectangleShape r2 (Vector2f(150,200)); // 2nd object
    r2.setFillColor(Color::Blue);
    r2.setPosition(Vector2f(120,160));


    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.setView(view);
        window.draw(background);
        window.draw(r1);
        window.draw(r2);
        view.setRotation(30); // affects all elements

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Here is result]